# How Can I Tell When an Activity Stops vs App Stops?

Tags: android, android-activity

I guess I still need to learn how Android apps flow. The title might not have been clear, so let me explain.

**Situation**:
I have a game which has a few different activities. For example, `MenuActivity`, `GameActivity`, and `HowToActivity`. The game starts at `MenuActivity` and plays a song set to loop. To have the same song play during `MenuActivity` and `HowToActivity`, uniterrupted, I have the song played from an implemented `Application.` If I press the home button, get a phone, or whatever, the song will continue to play. To prevent that, I need to stop the song when leaving the app.

**Problem**:
Currently, in `MenuActivity`, I have code to stop the song under the `protected void onStop()` function. This stops the song when leaving the app (Pressing the Home button, get a phone call), but it also stops the song when changing to another activity within the app, such as `HowToActivity`. So the question is, how can I tell the difference?

Comment: I think that you have to play song in service and stop service whenever you want

Comment: In both case while switching between activities and pressing home button it  will come to the onStop state, but the switching between activities you will be doing it programmatically in that case why you cant set a boolean value and check it on onStop methord, correct  me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesse,
You need to have a service that will do the job of playing the song.
You can easily start the service from any of the activity of your application. Also the service can be stopped by any of the activity.
Hence in the activity onCreate(), you can start the song player service, that will play the song even if the activity dies and new activity starts. Once your application is done with the song playing, just call stopService().
I hope this will solve your issue.

~Rajan

Comment: So if I implement it as a Service, and the user presses the home button or gets a phone call or something, it will automatically stop the service?

Comment: Jesse, It will not stop automatically. You need to have listener/observer for those. Like, You need to have a phone call listener within the service. So, whenever phone call is in progress, service can pause the music.

Comment: Perhaps so, but what I'm saying is, a service in and of itself does nothing for what I was asking.

Comment: @ Jesse J No, there is no such class that would handle the requirement mentioned by you of its own, But there are mechanism (broadcaset receiver, etc) using which, it can be achieved.

Comment: Ok, so you can tell if the user left the Activity and went to another one and basically put code in every other Activity they could go to stop the Service (bleah!) but how do you detect when they exit that app altogether? (onStop could be called simply because the screen went off, and I don't want THAT to stop my Service!)

Answer (score 1):

Typically what happens is that people read the phone state using a PhoneStateListener:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

This is why so many apps need the READ_PHONE_STATE permission, they're making sure you aren't answering a call while the app goes off and continues to do something annoying.  You can create a listener to check when things like this happen.  You shouldn't really change the behavior of the home key (and can't!), but instead, you can always listen for things like onPause() and onStop().

You probably want a background service that actually does the music playing, etc.., and then you want to control this service from your actual app when you get lifecycle events inside activities.  This makes your app a bit more modular (i.e., the thing that it's doing semantically is control the sound, download the stream, whatever), because the Activities control the UI, and the Services what happens behind the scenes.

Edit: tutorial for MediaPlayer from a service:

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

You might also want to look into using a wake lock, though it might not be strictly necessary.

Comment: So if I check for phone state, and check for Home and Back buttons, then that will cover the possible valid instances to stop the music?

Comment: You can't really check for home and back.  You should just handle it at onPause(), which is where you really want to watch out.

Comment: But, again, how would that help? If I indiscriminately stop the music at onPause(), I'll also be stopping it when I want it to continue.

Comment: That's why I said to play it in a service.  You can do something like setting a flag in your service when you're about to move to another activity in your app (it's like telling the service, "I'm going to another activity, so when I hit my onPause, don't stop the music yet."), and then the rest of the onPause() events get the real transitions out of the app.

Comment: Perhaps, but then I looked up how to communicate with a service to set/reset such a flag, which led to more confusing code. I give up. This is far more difficult then it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a receiver to capture the following intent:

```
Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
```

This will be called when the Home screen of the phone is launched. So you can stop music at that time rather than stopping onStop() of Activity.

But this will not help if the user launch an app by pressing Home key long time.

So try to play different musics on different Screens.

Comment: What if the user changed to another app by other means, for instance, by switching to the screen where you can select which app to go to, or because another app simply popped up on its own (e.g. an incoming phone call)?